# How to grant a user a Mongodb database privilege with Puppet?

Tags: mongodb, puppet

The user is created by the following Puppet resource:

```
mongodb::db { 'db1':
  user     => 'user1',
  password => 'password',
  roles    => ["dbAdmin", "dbOwner"],
}
```

Recently we have added a role `clusterMonitor@admin` in the MongoDB database. The roles are like this:

```
["clusterMonitor@admin", "dbAdmin", "dbOwner"].
```

How can we do this in Puppet? Any alternative way to make it work is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You add the user to the array in the `roles` attribute just like you wrote:

```
mongodb::db { 'db1':
  user     => 'user1',
  password => 'password',
  roles    => ["clusterMonitor@admin", "dbAdmin", "dbOwner"],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see the reply until now. I tried it but it didn't work. I got the error:

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see the reply until now. I tried it but it didn't work. I got the error:   

Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter roles failed on Mongodb_user[testPulsUser]: Invalid value "clusterMonitor@admin". Valid values match /^\w+$/. at /etc/puppet/environments/test/modules/mongodb/manifests/db.pp:41

This is my puppet code:
  mongodb::db { 'db1':
    user     => 'user1',
    password => 'password',
    roles => [ "clusterMonitor@admin","dbAdmin", "dbOwner"],
  }

I read some posts that I have to disable auth before I modify users/roles, is it possible that reason?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see the reply until now. I tried it but it didn't work. I got the error:   


Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter roles failed on Mongodb_user[testPulsUser]: Invalid value "clusterMonitor@admin". Valid values match /^\w+$/. at /etc/puppet/environments/test/modules/mongodb/manifests/db.pp:41
'

This is my puppet code:
'
mongodb::db { 'db1':
  user     => 'user1',
  password => 'password',
  roles => [ "clusterMonitor@admin","dbAdmin", "dbOwner"],
}
'